# Non-area based apportionment methods

Tags: r, intersection, apportion

I'm quite new to GIS data, and I currently have an issue where I have data on a specific variable coded in one set of geographic units and I need to convert it to another set of geographic units.  There is overlap between multiple units of the old geography to multiple units in the new geography.  **What methods are available to reapportion the variable from the old geography into the new geography?**  I'm aware of [the spatial overlap method](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6577_3b66f8d8f4984fb2807e91224defa854.html), but this really distorts my data in a way that isn't meaningful.  I'm working in R with shapefiles and SpatialPolygonsDataFrames.

If a concrete example helps, an analogous situation would be if I collected data from a survey of law enforcement agencies in the US that reported the number of guns confiscated during arrests.  Agencies would include state patrol, city police, the ATF, etc.  There is a an overlap in the jurisdictions of these agencies, some nested, some not.  How could I reapportion the survey results into a different geography, like US zip codes?  Using area overlap seems inappropriate in this situation, since the variable itself is dependent on more than just the jurisdiction area.

Related Question:
There is [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146762/how-to-aggregate-values-of-different-statistical-areas-that-are-overlapping), however, the answer focuses only on area-style apportions.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/joelgombin/spReapportion

Comment: @mdsumner Thank you for the link to an implementation.  However, I'm also looking for some insight into the theory of apportionment.  This function can be passed a `weight_matrix`; what methods are available to develop those weights?  Are there other methods?  This is the sort of question I'm asking, beyond just an implementation.

Comment: If you aren't using spatial overlap as a weighting method, you probably want some sort of table join. You need something to weight how the portion from form dataset A is assigned to dataset B.