# Clipping Census tract shapefiles to boundaries of City Council shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, census

I am currently working on a project where I am using Census tract data to figure out the population characteristics of the city council districts of several major US cities. For the cities that I have completed so far, I have been simply uploading the KML files for both the city council districts and the corresponding Census tracts (clipped to the city boundaries when I can find them) to Google Maps. I use Google Earth when the files exceed the 5MB limit on Google Maps. Then, I go through the tracts one by one and in a spreadsheet I record which city council district(s) they are in.

As you can guess, it takes an excruciatingly long time to do this manually.

I was wondering if there was a way to run some sort of script in ArcGIS Desktop that could do this automatically, recording the percent of the area of each Census tract contained within each district?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are you currently using any GIS desktop software to process your various GIS layers (e.g. ArcGIS, QGIS)?

Comment: I was fooling around with ArcGIS for a while, but after a while I realized that I didn't know enough to justify using the program over Google Maps. I would be happy to start using ArcGIS again or any other GIS software if it is more effective than what I am currently doing with Google Maps.

Comment: Maptitude from Caliper would include all of the Census tract outlines and it is incredibly easy to use.

Comment: I would suggest looking at QGIS since it's free. Google isn't really a GIS, it's mapping, and what you want to do is more a geoprocessing/analysis. The analysis you're describing is a pretty basic GIS process, particularly in the way you describe and not much more to do apportioning. Similar question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133832/ for QGIS. I've answered a few others aimed at ArcGIS, but of course that costs. And from what I understand, QGIS is a little more KML friendly if you don't have a different source format to start from.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to ArcGIS, you could use [Select By Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) to select census tracts that are within the city council districts. You will need ArcGIS friendly files for this (ArcGIS is not super KML-friendly, though you can convert from KML with [this tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004w000000)). Census Tracts are available on the [the U.S. Census website](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html). City boundary files should not be difficult to find.

You can export selected features as a dBASE table (.dbf), which can be opened in Excel and saved as a .csv or .xslx file. In the attribute table in ArcGIS, use the drop-down in the top left and 'Export...'

For calculating the percentage of one polygon (i.e. census tract) within another polygon (i.e. district boundary), look at the [overlay analysis tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018p00000004000000) in ArcGIS. If I understand your question correctly, you might only need to use the [Tabulate Intersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000044000000) tool.

Comment: Thanks, this is good for when I cannot find Census tract files that are clipped to the city boundaries. Just to clarify, I have both the Shapefiles and the KML files (it's just that Google only really accepts KML files).

EDIT: now is there also a way to send the data to a spreadsheet? For instance, if 50% of tract 001001 is in district 1, can I send this row of data to a spreadsheet using ArcGIS or something else?

Comment: I updated my answer.